# get last id form database in laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to get only the last inserted data from my database.
Here, I get all data from the database but I want only the last value.
This is ProductController.php

```
function indextwo() 
{
    return DB::select("select * from  products");
}
```

This is web.php

```
Route::get('products_link', [ProductController::class, 'indextwo']);
```

Here is my current output:

[image: In this link here is all data I have inserted but I only want last data]

Comment: you can use last() method. return Products::all()->last(); or you can use orderBy to order and then get the last record

Comment: Just an FYI, the above method isn't very efficient as using `all()` will retrieve and load **all** rows from the database and then get the last one in the list. It would be much, much better to use the leverage the database and just retrieve the one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last id using `Query Builder` and `Eloquent`.

**Query Builder**

```
function indextwo() {
    return DB::table('products')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
}
```

**Eloquent**

```
function indextwo() {
    return Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
}
```

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed If this has answered your question, please may you mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [latest()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest) function for get

```
$user = DB::select("select * from  products")
            ->latest()
            ->first();
```

Comment: `latest()` orders by `created_at` if you don't pass a field to it. To have `latest()` use the id column, you would need to do `latest('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Model name direct in controller like your model name is "Product" and also use limit() and latest()

```
$user = Products::latest()->limit(1);
```

Comment: `latest()` orders by `created_at` if you don't pass a field to it. To have `latest()` use the id column, you would need to do `latest('id')`. Also, `limit()` doesn't return results, you would still need to retrieve the data using something like `first()` which would make the `limit(1)` call redundant.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way you can follow

```
Product::query()->latest()->first()
```

It will return you the latest inserted data according to order by id desc.

Another way :

```
Product::query()->orderByDesc('id')->first();
```

Comment: `latest()` orders by `created_at` if you don't pass a field to it. To have `latest()` use the id column, you would need to do `latest('id')`.